# Firebase functions v1 configuration not retrieving configuration

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on migrating my firebase functions version from the beta to the recently released v1 per the instructions listed on their website here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

The specific piece I'm failing on is described as:

> `functions.config().firebase` has been removed. If you'd like to access the config values from your Firebase project, use process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG instead:

```
let firebaseConfig = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG);
/* {  databaseURL: 'https://databaseName.firebaseio.com',
       storageBucket: 'projectId.appspot.com',
       projectId: 'projectId' }
*/
```

So I've updated my version as well as my code and now receive the following:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (functions\index.js:25:72)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at \npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:21:11
at Object.<anonymous> (\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:61:3)
```

The property "key" it's referring to is a property on my config object, which I'm trying to access by doing:

```
let firebaseConfig = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG);

// let firebaseConfig = functions.config().firebase;
const SENDGRID_API_KEY = encodeURIComponent(firebaseConfig.sendgrid.key);
```

When I run

```
firebase functions:config:get
```

It shows my config as existing:

```
{
  "gmail": {
    "password": "pwdValue",
    "email": "emailvalue"
  },
  "sendgrid": {
    "key": "keyvalue"
  }
}
```

I've also double checked the .runtimeconfig.json file and it's the exact same as what that command returns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're misunderstanding the change that happened in v1.  The change is that `firebase.config().firebase` is no longer to be used, in favor of the Firebase SDK automatically picking up your project default credentials via `process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG`.

That doesn't mean that `firebase.config()` has gone away.  You still use that for your own configuration values that you set with `firebase functions:config:get` *exactly* like you did before v1.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about how to use environment variables here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env

You need to omit the `firebase` property when calling a custom config variable, like so:

`functions.config().sendgrid.key`